# Compute the automaton for the modular group

Tags: coxeter-groups, modular-group

The modular group $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ has 3 generators $A,B,C$, where
$$A:z\to z+1,\quad B:z\to z-1,\quad C:z\to -1/z.$$

I want to compute the automaton that recognize the words of the modular group, where the input symbols are just $\{A,B,C\}$. But the above representation is not in the standard form of a coxeter group system.

My problem is: how can one do the computation in this case? Or are there any programs that do the work available?

Answer (score 3):

The [Warwick automatic groups software](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9507202v1.pdf) provides the means for doing this (in particular, the [KBMAG](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~mareg/download/kbmag2/) program). Alternatively you can use Alun William's [MAF](http://maffsa.sourceforge.net/) (Monoid Automata Factory) package.

There is also an [interface to KBMAG](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/kbmag.html) provided in the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) computer algebra system.